# how to count letters in a word and display the word depending on how many the letters are

Tags: javascript, java

For example, if  I input the word "HELLO"
the output must be

HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO
HELLO

because hello have 5 letters it will display 5 hello's too.
I need the code for java please I'm new with this

Comment: This is not a website where we do your homework for you. Make an attempt, show it to us, explain what the exact problem is and where exactly you are confused.

Comment: Hi @WencyBolaten . Welcome to Stackoverflow. You see you are getting downvotes. This means, people don't see any research effort that you made in your question. So help yourself, and improve your question, show what you have done, what examples you found. Also you specify the tags javascript and Java, which one do you need a solution for? These are two entirely different programming languages (see: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_javascript.xml)

Comment: Hints: 1) `java.lang.String#size` is the size of a string. 2) Then use a `for` loop to output that string that many number of times. 3) Going to the lectures can be useful.

Comment: You know that js and java are two completely different languages ??

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
 var repeat = word => (word+" ").repeat(word.length);
```

in javascript you can use String.repeat with String.length to get the desired result, usecase:

```
console.log( repeat( "HELLO" ))
```

In Java:

```
final /*help the compiler optimise out the size call*/ String s = "HELLO";
for (int n = 0; n < s.size(); ++n){
    System.out.print((n == 0 ? "" : " ") + s);
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Sadly the OP wants a Java solution. (Even more distressing is they want it for free.)

Comment: @bathsheba no, you want a java solution. You removed the js tag :/

Comment: Because it was at odds with the question text: "I need the code for java please " is pretty explicit. Let's not get into a tag war.

Comment: @bathsheba oh yeah sorry, ive overread that :/

Comment: I bunged in the Java solution so I could upvote.

Comment: @bathsheba adding a java solution and downvoting mys wouldbe been okay too, however i appreciate this solution, thanks ;)

Comment: I put the tag back in. You have a point in suspecting the OP might not know the difference. They could just have easily said "I need the code for javascript please">

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use length attribute of a string to find out how many characters it contains then use a loop to show string length times.